# the movement of my object is not smooth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm making a mobile game based on android. When I was making a transfer code for my player object, I wrote code like this.

```
void Update() {
    if(Input.touchcount == 1)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            //Move
        }
        else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            //Move
        }
    }
}
```

It's moving at right direction and speed that I wanted. But when I touch quicker, these codes are don't working smoothly. I mean the player object is not moving smoothly.

Is there any solution for this problem?

P.S. I cant use `AddForce` in rigidbody

Comment: `TouchPhase.Stationary`? Why not `TouchPhase.Move`?

Comment: oh! it's working now!!! i thought TouchPhase.Move will don't work. Really thank you my friend!